# getting IOException : Peer refused the connection (BlackBerry)

Tags: blackberry, connection

Can anyone tell me why i am getting this IOException:smileytongue:eer refused the connection??? I was testing my application yesterday it was working fine..but today when i opened it i cannot log int my application...i cannot login from the simulator.

.i hve tried appending ";deviceside=true" , ";deviceside=false" and removing it from the url..but nothing seems to work even on simulator...Iwas able to login until yesterday...no change in the code has been made...

The login url is Https url..but i dont think that may be the issue since i was able to access it till  yesterdey...

Can any one help..??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd double check that the server you are talking to is still up (can you connect to it from a browser on your computer?) and also ensure that the Windows Firewall is not blocking traffic from the simulator.  Also, unless you're just using Direct TCP and/or Wi-Fi, make sure that MDS simulator is up and running BEFORE you launch the simulator.